# how to build a triangular slider?

Tags: css, slider, geometry

Good afternoon!

I have a **triangular** slider design but no HTML:
[triangular slider design at the bottom](http://munka.online1.hu/4x42/1.html)

How it functions:

- if you hover over a slide (a triagle) the slide [grows a bit like this](http://snag.gy/HOtur.jpg)
- if you click on it a lightbox opens
- if you click on the gray next/prev arrows another set of 6 images appears

I've tried to use

- CSS border-triangles+border-image
- rotating individual triangle images forth and their container back
- map tag for hover and click

but no real solution. I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: What is your question? More importantly: [*what have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Thank you for the question. This is my 1st one.

Comment: @SzépeViktor Please read his question again.  We don't know what you are asking for.  What's the purpose? what's the ask

Comment: @SzépeViktor, in that case, please take some time to review the [faq].

Comment: @ntgCleaner ... i like your double-content solution on your site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want to do is possible via CSS3.
It must be done thinking, that it will not be triangles for older browser.
So, you start first building your slider in square shap.
The second part is to rotate squares, hide half of it , and ....

I copied one of my dabblet into liveweave.com, so you can open it in IE8 if you wish: http://liveweave.com/UU2oOZ

it is not your solution, this menu is vertical), but it is an example that can help you to start someting.

Comment: few of my dabbets with triangle:  dabblet.com/gist/3482088 , dabblet.com/gist/5020696, dabblet.com/gist/5190765 . The thing is to see what it's like if CSS3 fails.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have that whole parallelogram slide back and forth, or the individual triangle images? Perhaps if you have an example of what the next slide would look like, that would be helpful.

Comment: as I edited above: prev/next slides all 6 images, clicking on an image opens a lightbox

Answer (score 1):

If the above link is what you are looking for, you could also just use transparent png's that are already triangle shaped, then use absolute positioning to make the elements overlap. This isn't as elegant as using CSS3, but it is a universal solution for browser support. I think we need more details about what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you! I am asking here because I need an elegant solution.